# BlockingCollection Max Size

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, concurrency

I understand that BlockingCollection using ConcurrentQueue has a boundedcapacity of 100.

However I'm unsure as to what that means.

I'm trying to achieve a concurrent cache which, can dequeue, can deque/enque in one operation if the queue size is too large, (i.e. loose messages when the cache overflows).  Is there a way to use boundedcapacity for this or is it better to manually do this or create a new collection.

Basically I have a reading thread and several writing threads.  I would like it if the data in the queue is the "freshest" of all the writers.

Comment: May be you need kinda of the back event to inform writers about freshest data?

Answer (score 3):

A bounded capacity of N means that if the queue already contains N items, any thread attempting to add another item will block until a different thread removes an item.

What you seem to want is a different concept - you want most recently added item to be the first item that is dequeued by the consuming thread.

You can achieve that by using a [`ConcurrentStack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd267331.aspx) rather than a ConcurrentQueue for the underlying store.

You would use [`this constructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd287133.aspx) and pass in a `ConcurrentStack`.

For example:

```
var blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<int>(new ConcurrentStack<int>());
```

By using `ConcurrentStack`, you ensure that each item that the consuming thread dequeues will be the freshest item in the queue at that time.

Also note that if you specify an upper bound for the blocking collection, you can use [`BlockingCollection.TryAdd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267245.aspx) which will return `false` if the collection was full at the time you called it.

Comment: based on my freshest statement that is true.  however i would still want the queue dispatched in the order they are enqueued.  It seems like it may be best to do a 
if(q.count>x)
{q.take();//donothing}
q.add(newitem)
before every add to keep the size down, however if another thread takes after length is counted then you end up removing a message unnecessarily

Comment: Hmm I don't think I really understand your requirement properly... But if you specify an upper bound for the blocking collection, you can use [`BlockingCollection.TryAdd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267245.aspx) and it will return false if the queue is full - can you use that?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you're trying to build something like an MRU (most recently used) cache. `BlockingCollection` is not the best way to do that.

I would suggest instead that you use a [LinkedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx). It's not thread-safe, so you'll have to provide your own synchronization, but that's not too tough. Your enqueue method looks like this:

```
LinkedList<MyType> TheQueue = new LinkedList<MyType>();
object listLock = new object();

void Enqueue(MyType item)
{
    lock (listLock)
    {
        TheQueue.AddFirst(item);
        while (TheQueue.Count > MaxQueueSize)
        {
            // Queue overflow. Reduce to max size.
            TheQueue.RemoveLast();
        }
    }
}
```

And dequeue is even easier:

```
MyType Dequeue()
{
    lock (listLock)
    {
        return (TheQueue.Count > 0) ? TheQueue.RemoveLast() : null;
    }
}
```

It's a little more involved if you want the consumers to do non-busy waits on the queue. You can do it with `Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.Pulse`. See the example on the [Monitor.Pulse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse.aspx) page for an example.

Update:

It occurs to me that you could do the same thing with a circular buffer (an array). Just maintain head and tail pointers. You insert at `head` and remove at `tail`. If you go to insert, and `head == tail`, then you need to increment `tail`, which effectively removes the previous `tail` item.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a custom `BlockingCollection` that holds the N most recent elements, and drops the oldest elements when it's full, you could create one quite easily based on a [`Channel<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1). The [Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/) are intended to be used in asynchronous scenarios, but making them block the consumer is trivial and should not cause any unwanted side-effects (like deadlocks), even if used in an environment with a `SynchronizationContext` installed.

```
public class MostRecentBlockingCollection<T>
{
    private readonly Channel<T> _channel;

    public MostRecentBlockingCollection(int capacity)
    {
        _channel = Channel.CreateBounded<T>(new BoundedChannelOptions(capacity)
        {
            FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.DropOldest,
        });
    }

    public bool IsCompleted => _channel.Reader.Completion.IsCompleted;

    public void Add(T item)
        => _channel.Writer.WriteAsync(item).AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    public T Take()
        => _channel.Reader.ReadAsync().AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    public void CompleteAdding() => _channel.Writer.Complete();

    public IEnumerable<T> GetConsumingEnumerable()
    {
        while (_channel.Reader.WaitToReadAsync().AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult())
            while (_channel.Reader.TryRead(out var item))
                yield return item;
    }
}
```

The `MostRecentBlockingCollection` class blocks only the consumer. The producer can always add items in the collection, causing (potentially) some previously added elements to be dropped.

Adding cancellation support should be straightforward, since the `Channel<T>` API already supports it. Adding support for timeout is less trivial, but shouldn't be very difficult to do.